# sharepoint listview web part access deined error

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I have created listview web part do display infopath form . When i open the forms using adminstrator login everything works fine but when i login using normal user account the fallowing error is displayed .

"Error: Access denid"

Can anyone give solution for this..

Answer (score 0):

The user doesn't have rights to view the list the listview web part is reading from?

Answer (score 0):

The only time I've had such errors is when a resource refferenced from a webpart (whether custom or not), is being read from the file system. e.g. DataFormWebPart reading an xslt from the file system (layouts folder) instead of the style library. I would just double check that you haven't got a file like an xslt being called from the file system. If you have, try storing it somewhere within SharePoint e.g. Style Library.